# Trying to sum a list

Tags: python, loops, sum

I am trying to sum a list, but am having trouble doing so. It seems that my code creates a seperate list for each iteration in the list. Are there any suggestions you have to summing all these numbers together?

```
def looping():
    for i in range(len(flat)):

    call_value_bs= []
    put_value_bs= []
    sigma_percentage = terminal_prices.std() / 100
    item = flat[i]

    r = .015
    S = item
    #print(S)
    K= 120
    T = 365/365
    sigma = sigma_percentage

    d1 = (np.log(S/K)) + ((r + sigma**2 /2)*T) / (sigma*np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1 - (sigma*np.sqrt(T))


    call_value_bs.append(((S*norm.cdf(d1))- K * math.exp(-1 *r*T) * (norm.cdf(d2))))
    
    call_value_bs = [ 0 if x < 0 else x for x in call_value_bs]
    
    
    
    sum_call = sum(call_value_bs)
    print(sum_call)
```

[image: This is the output I would like to sum together]

[image: This is the output I get when I sum them]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to calculate the call option value for a sequence of different asset (or stock) prices in `flat`.

I have adjusted your `call_value_bs.append()` statement, moved some other code around, added some sample values for `flat` and used a hardcoded value for `sigma_percentage` so that I could provide you with an actual working code sample.

This code should do what you're attempting:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
def looping():
    flat = [100, 110, 120, 130, 140]
    call_value_bs= []
    put_value_bs= []
    for i in range(len(flat)):
        #sigma_percentage = terminal_prices.std() / 100
        sigma_percentage = 0.20
        item = flat[i]

        r = .015
        S = item
        #print(S)
        K= 120
        T = 365/365
        sigma = sigma_percentage

        d1 = (np.log(S/K)) + ((r + sigma**2 /2)*T) / (sigma*np.sqrt(T))
        d2 = d1 - (sigma*np.sqrt(T))


        call_value_bs.append(S*norm.cdf(d1)- K * math.exp(-1 *r*T) * norm.cdf(d2))

    call_value_bs = [ 0 if x < 0 else x for x in call_value_bs]
    sum_call = sum(call_value_bs)
    print(sum_call)        

looping()
```

Here's the sample output:

```
54.99775102555421
```

Comment: @ErenLulu123 did this answer your question? Do you need more help?